# How to access from two screens to the third using Python and Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, screen, kivy-language

I'm just learning the Python , please don't judge too harshly.  I'm working on a coffee shop position count program using Kivy.  I've run into a few issues that I can't resolve.

There are 4 screens in the reduced copy of my program: MainWindow, CoffeeWindow, TeaWindow and SumMenu.
There are buttons on the CoffeeWindow and TeaWindow screens, the program count clicks on these buttons and should show the result in the SumMenu screen .

I can show in SumMenu the number of clicks on the buttons from CoffeeWindow or TeaWindow, but I can't show the result from both screens at the same time, I tried different ways, but I constantly encounter errors.

Please help me solve my problem, thanks in advance!

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class SumMenu(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        if self.manager.ids.coffee.coff: self.ids.label1.text = ""
        if self.manager.ids.coffee.coff1 != 0: self.ids.label1.text += f"coffee 1 : {self.manager.ids.coffee.coff1}\n"
        if self.manager.ids.coffee.coff2 != 0: self.ids.label1.text += f"coffee 2 : {self.manager.ids.coffee.coff2}\n"
        if self.manager.ids.coffee.coff3 != 0: self.ids.label1.text += f"coffee 3 : {self.manager.ids.coffee.coff3}\n"
        if self.manager.ids.coffee.coff4 != 0: self.ids.label1.text += f"coffee 4 : {self.manager.ids.coffee.coff4}\n"

        #if self.manager.ids.tea.tea: self.ids.label1.text = ""
        #if self.manager.ids.tea.tea1 != 0: self.ids.label2.text += f"tea 1 : {self.manager.ids.tea.tea1}\n"
        #if self.manager.ids.tea.tea2 != 0: self.ids.label2.text += f"tea 2 : {self.manager.ids.tea.tea2}\n"
        #if self.manager.ids.tea.tea3 != 0: self.ids.label2.text += f"tea 3 : {self.manager.ids.tea.tea3}\n"
        #if self.manager.ids.tea.tea4 != 0: self.ids.label2.text += f"tea 4 : {self.manager.ids.tea.tea4}\n"




class CoffeeWindow(Screen):
    coff = True
    coff_tup = []
    def count(self, num):

        self.coff_tup.append(num)

        self.coff1 = self.coff_tup.count(1)
        self.coff2 = self.coff_tup.count(2)
        self.coff3 = self.coff_tup.count(3)
        self.coff4 = self.coff_tup.count(4)


class TeaWindow(Screen):
    tea = True
    tea_tup = []
    def count(self, num):

        self.tea_tup.append(num)

        self.tea1 = self.tea_tup.count(1)
        self.tea2 = self.tea_tup.count(2)
        self.tea3 = self.tea_tup.count(3)
        self.tea4 = self.tea_tup.count(4)


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
<CoffeeButton@Button>:
    font_size: "23sp"
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.12
    bold: True

<HorizBoxLayout@BoxLayout>:
    padding: 30
    spacing: 25
    orientation: "horizontal"

<SumLabel@Label>:
    bold: True
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"


WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
        id: main
    CoffeeWindow:
        id: coffee
    TeaWindow:
        id: tea
    SumMenu:
        id: summenu


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main_window"

    HorizBoxLayout:

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "Go to Coffee"
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'center_y' : 0.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "coffee"
                app.root.transition.direction = "left"

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "Go to Tea"
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'center_y' : 0.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "tea"
                app.root.transition.direction = "left"


<CoffeeWindow>:
    name: "coffee"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        size_hint: 1, 0.8
        pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5, 'top' : 0.95}
        padding: 40
        spacing: 40

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "coffee 1"
            on_release:
                root.count(1)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "coffee 2"
            on_release:
                root.count(2)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "coffee 3"
            on_release:
                root.count(3)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "coffee 4"
            on_release:
                root.count(4)

        Button:
            bold: True
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: "18sp"
            pos_hint: {'right' : 0.5, 'y' : 0}
            text: "Show Menu"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "summenu"
                app.root.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            bold: True
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: "18sp"
            pos_hint: {'right' : 0.5, 'y' : 0}
            text: "Go to Main"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main_window"
                app.root.transition.direction = "right"


<TeaWindow>:
    name: "tea"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        size_hint: 1, 0.8
        pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5, 'top' : 0.95}
        padding: 40
        spacing: 40

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "tea 1"
            on_release:
                root.count(1)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "tea 2"
            on_release:
                root.count(2)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "tea 3"
            on_release:
                root.count(3)

        CoffeeButton:
            text: "tea 4"
            on_release:
                root.count(4)

        Button:
            bold: True
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: "18sp"
            pos_hint: {'right' : 0.5, 'y' : 0}
            text: "Show Menu"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "summenu"
                app.root.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            bold: True
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: "18sp"
            pos_hint: {'right' : 0.5, 'y' : 0}
            text: "Go to Main"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main_window"
                app.root.transition.direction = "right"


<SumMenu>:
    name: "summenu"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 30
        spacing: 15
        pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'center_y' : 0.57}
        size_hint: 1, 0.88

        SumLabel:
            id: label1

        SumLabel:
            id: label2

    Button:
        bold: True
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        font_size: "18sp"
        pos_hint: {'right' : 0.5, 'y' : 0}
        text: "Go to Main"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main_window"
            app.root.transition.direction = "right"
```

Comment: Instead of setting different attributes for each counter, count and set values locally.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: check this tuto i uploaded recently : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmvNutNqKWM&t=116s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try storing all of the button click counts in a dictionary that get's updated whenever one of the buttons is pressed.  Then in your summ screen you can simply build your label text based off of the keys and values in the dictionaries for the Tea and Coffee screens.

For example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class SumMenu(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        coffee = self.manager.ids.coffee.clickCounter
        tea = self.manager.ids.tea.clickCounter
        self.set_label_text("Coffee", coffee, self.ids.label1)
        self.set_label_text("Tea", tea, self.ids.label2)

    def set_label_text(self, title, counts, label):
        label.text = ""
        for item_num, count in counts.items():
            label.text += f"{title} {item_num} : {count}\n\n"


class CoffeeWindow(Screen):
    clickCounter = {}

    def count(self, num):
        self.clickCounter.setdefault(num, 0)
        self.clickCounter[num] += 1

class TeaWindow(Screen):

    clickCounter = {}

    def count(self, num):
        self.clickCounter.setdefault(num, 0)
        self.clickCounter[num] += 1


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```